# Passing Javascript variable to PHP variable to use on query without redirect

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, sql-server, modal-dialog

Here's my problem:

I have an input that has onclick event getRet('somevalue') passing 'somevalue',

**retrackView.php** - html

```
<input type="text" style="border: 0; color:blue;" id="return_type"
class="return_type" name="return_type" data-toggle="modal" 
data-target="#myModalSS_SKU" data-remote="false" readonly="readonly"
title="Click Me" value="<?=$objResult["RETURN_TYPE"];?>" 
onclick="getRet('<?=$objResult["RETURN_TYPE"];?><?=$objResult["IMEI"];?>');">
```

I also have a javascript function to post 'somevalue'

**retrackView.php** - inside

```
function getRet(ret) {
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: 'retrackView.php',
      data: ({"data1": ret}),
      success: function(data) {
        alert(data);
      }
    });
}
```

and I have a PHP script inside the modal to get that 'somevalue' to use in query to populate the modal values

**retrackView.php** - inside PHP

```
$strSQL1 = "select * from sch_orders where return_type + IMEI = '.$_POST['data1'].'";

$result2=sqlsrv_query( $conn,$strSQL1, $params2,array( "Scrollable" => 'keyset')); 
while($objResult1 = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $result2,SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC ))

//..... then I used it like : 
<label>
<?if (isset($objResult["DATE_RECEIVED_WHSE"])){ 
    print date('m-d-Y h:i A', strtotime($objResult["DATE_RECEIVED_WHSE"]));
}?>
</label>
```

The problem is `.$_POST['data1'].` has no value [undefined index : data1]

here's my some modal code:

```
<div id="myModalSS_SKU" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
      <div class="modal-dialog" style="height:540px; max-height:740px; width:1030px; max-width:1030px;">
        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header" style="background-color: #333666;">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Retrack-Globe</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body" style="height:540px; max-height:740px; width:1530px; max-width:1530px;"><!--style=".modal.large{width:10000px;}"-->
                                                                        <?//target="_blank" ?>
            <!--form action="customerView.php" method="post"-->
                <input type="image" src="images/print.png" width="30" height="30" title="print" left= "-100" onclick="window.open('print.php')"> <!--onclick="Print()"--> 
                <!--input style="font-size: 15px;" id="imei"><?=$objResult["IMEI"];?></input>
                </input>
            </form-->

        <? 
        $ret = (isset($_POST["ret"]) ? $_POST["ret"] : 'Track01');
        $serverName = "RLLAMES-PC\MSSQL2005";
            $uid = "sa";
            $pwd = "5chep0d";
            $connectionInfo = array( "UID"=>$uid,
                    "PWD"=>$pwd,
                    "Database"=>"RETRACK",
                    "ReturnDatesAsStrings"=> true);

            $conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);          echo($_POST['data1'].'================================================================================');
            $strSQL1 = "select * from sch_orders where return_type + IMEI = 'DSW-STDOANSAMaas16042801681'";
            $params2 = array ($getKeyWord, $getKeyWord, $getKeyWord, $getKeyWord, $getKeyWord, $ret );
            $result2=sqlsrv_query( $conn,$strSQL1, $params2,array( "Scrollable" => 'keyset'));
            while($objResult1 = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $result2,SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC )) {
            $var_imei = $objResult1["IMEI"];
            $var_icscase = $objResult1["ICSCase"];
            }

            $strSQL = "select * from sch_orders where (imei  = '" . $var_imei . "'  or newimei = '" . $var_imei . "' ) AND ICSCASE  = '" . $var_icscase . "' " ;
            $params1 = array ($getKeyWord, $getKeyWord, $getKeyWord, $getKeyWord, $getKeyWord, $ret );
            $result1=sqlsrv_query( $conn,$strSQL, $params1,array( "Scrollable" => 'keyset'));
            $count=count($result1);     

             while($objResult = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $result1,SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC )) {
            //$ret =  (isset($_GET['ret']) ? $_GET['ret'] : 'TRACK01' );
            //echo $ret; 
            //echo $getKeyWord;

/*if(isset($_GET['txtKeyword'])){
        $getKeyWord = $_GET['txtKeyword'];
        $fieldname = $_GET['cbSearch'];
        $ret = (isset($_POST["ret"]) ? $_POST["ret"] : 'Track01');
        //$ret = $_GET["ret"];
        //echo isset($ret) ? $ret : 'None';

        if ($getKeyWord != ""){
            //echo '1'; die;

            $serverName = "RLLAMES-PC\MSSQL2005";
            $uid = "sa";
            $pwd = "5chep0d";
            $connectionInfo = array( "UID"=>$uid,
                    "PWD"=>$pwd,
                    "Database"=>"RETRACK",
                    "ReturnDatesAsStrings"=> true);

            $conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);

            $strSQL = "select * from sch_orders where mobile =  (?) or invoice = (?) or imei = (?)  or newimei = (?) or mybss = (?) " ;
            $params1 = array ($getKeyWord, $getKeyWord, $getKeyWord, $getKeyWord, $getKeyWord, $ret );
            $result1=sqlsrv_query( $conn,$strSQL, $params1,array( "Scrollable" => 'keyset'));
            $count=count($result1);     

             while($objResult = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $result1,SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC )) { */?>

        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <label><?if (isset($objResult["DATE_REQUESTED"])){
                                print date('m-d-Y h:i A', strtotime($objResult["DATE_REQUESTED"]));
                            }?></label>
                </td>
                <td>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <label><?if (isset($objResult["DATE_RECEIVED_WHSE"])){
                                print date('m-d-Y h:i A', strtotime($objResult["DATE_RECEIVED_WHSE"]));
                            }?></label>
                </td>
                <td>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <label><?if (isset($objResult["DATE_FORWARDED_SC"])){
                                print date('m-d-Y h:i A', strtotime($objResult["DATE_FORWARDED_SC"]));
                            }?></label>
                </td>
                <td>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <label><?if (isset($objResult["DATE_RETURNED_WHSE"])){
                                print date('m-d-Y h:i A', strtotime($objResult["DATE_RETURNED_WHSE"]));
                            }?></label>
                </td>
                <td>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <label><?if (isset($objResult["DATE_DELIVERED_STORE"])){
                                print date('m-d-Y h:i A', strtotime($objResult["DATE_DELIVERED_STORE"]));
                            }?></label>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <a href="" title=""><img src="images/drq.png" alt="Smiley face" width="65" height="45"  align="left"></a>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <a href="" title="Go to DB Schenker site"><img src="images/arrow.png" alt="Smiley face" width="45" height="85" align="left"></a>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <a href="" title="<?if (isset($objResult["SLA_DRCW"])){ print "SLA is " .  $objResult["SLA_DRCW"] . " day/s,&#013;Upon date pulled out."; }?>">
                    <img src="images/drcw.png" alt="Smiley face" width="65" height="55"  align="left"></a>
                <? if (isset($objResult["DATE_REQUESTED"]) and isset($objResult["DATE_RECEIVED_WHSE"])) {
                    $date_drq = date_create($objResult["DATE_REQUESTED"]);
                   $date_drcw = date_create($objResult["DATE_RECEIVED_WHSE"]);
                   $drcwDiffs = date_diff($date_drq,$date_drcw);
                   $drcwDiff = $drcwDiffs->format("%R%a days");

                     $drcw = $objResult["SLA_DRCW"]-$drcwDiff;
                    if ($drcw>=0) {?><img src= "images/like.jpg" width="16" height="16" title="like"> <?echo abs($drcw) . 'day/s' ; 
                    }else{?><img src= "images/dislike.jpg" width="16" height="16" title="dislike"> <?echo abs($drcw) . 'day/s'; 
                    } 
                }?>


                </td>
                <td>
                    <a href="" title="Go to DB Schenker site"><img src="images/arrow.png" alt="Smiley face" width="45" height="85" align="left"></a>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <a href="" title="<?if (isset($objResult["SLA_DFSC"])){print "SLA is " .  $objResult["SLA_DFSC"] . " day/s,&#013;Upon date received in whse.";}?>">
                    <img src="images/dfsc.png" alt="Smiley face" width="65" height="55" align="left"></a>   
                    <?if (isset($objResult["DATE_RECEIVED_WHSE"]) and isset($objResult["DATE_FORWARDED_SC"])) {
                   $date_drcw = date_create($objResult["DATE_RECEIVED_WHSE"]);
                   $date_dfsc = date_create($objResult["DATE_FORWARDED_SC"]);
                   $dfscDiffs = date_diff($date_drcw,$date_dfsc);
                   $dfscDiff = $dfscDiffs->format("%R%a days");

                     $dfsc = $objResult["SLA_DFSC"]-$dfscDiff;
                    /*if ($dfsc>=0) {?><img src= "images/like.jpg" width="16" height="16" title="like"> <?echo abs($dfsc) . 'day/s' ; 
                    }else{?><img src= "images/dislike.jpg" width="16" height="16" title="dislike"> <?echo abs($dfsc) . 'day/s'; 
                    }*/
                }?>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <a href="" title="Go to DB Schenker site"><img src="images/arrow.png" alt="Smiley face" width="45" height="85" align="left"></a>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <a href="" title="<?if (isset($objResult["SLA_DRTW"])){print "SLA is " .  $objResult["SLA_DRTW"] . " day/s,&#013;Upon date forwarded in service center.";}?>">
                    <img src="images/drtw.png" alt="Smiley face" width="65" height="55" align="left"></a>
                <?if (isset($objResult["DATE_FORWARDED_SC"]) and isset($objResult["DATE_RETURNED_WHSE"])) {

                   $date_drtw = date_create($objResult["DATE_RETURNED_WHSE"]);
                   $date_drcw = date_create($objResult["DATE_RECEIVED_WHSE"]);
                   $drtwDiffs = date_diff($date_drcw,$date_drtw);
                   $drtwDiff = $drtwDiffs->format("%R%a days");

                      $drtw = $objResult["SLA_DFSC"]-$drtwDiff;
                        if ($drtw>=0) {?><img src="images/like.jpg" width="16" height="16" title="like"> <?echo  abs($drtw) . 'day/s'; 
                        }else{?><img src="images/dislike.jpg" width="16" height="16" title="dislike"> <?echo  abs($drtw) . 'day/s'; 
                        }
                }?>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <a href="" title="Go to DB Schenker site"><img src="images/arrow.png" alt="Smiley face" width="45" height="85" align="left"></a>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <a href="" title="<?if (isset($objResult["SLA_DDS"])){print "SLA is " .  $objResult["SLA_DDS"] . " day/s,&#013;Upon date returned in whse.";}?>"><img src="images/dds.png" alt="Smiley face" width="65" height="55"  align="left"></a>
                <?if (isset($objResult["DATE_DELIVERED_STORE"]) and isset($objResult["DATE_RETURNED_WHSE"])) {

                   $date_dds = date_create($objResult["DATE_DELIVERED_STORE"]);
                   $date_drtw = date_create($objResult["DATE_RETURNED_WHSE"]);
                   $ddsDiffs = date_diff($date_drtw,$date_dds);
                   $ddsDiff = $ddsDiffs->format("%R%a days");
                    //echo $SLA_DRTW . $drtwDiff;
                      $dds = $objResult["SLA_DDS"]-$ddsDiff;
                        if ($dds>=0) {?><img src="images/like.jpg"  width="16" height="16" title="like"> <?echo abs($dds) . 'day/s'; 
                        }else{?><img src="images/dislike.jpg"  width="16" height="16" title="dislike"> <?echo  abs($dds) . 'day/s'; 
                        }
                }?>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <?if (isset($objResult["ATT_DRQ"])) {?>
                        <a href="<?echo "/RETRACK/imgpdf/" . $objResult["ATT_DRQ"] ?>" download = "<? echo $objResult["ATT_DRQ"]; ?>">Download POD</a>

                    <?}else{?>
                        <label style="font-weight:normal;">No File</label>
                    <?}?>
                </td>
                <td>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <?if (isset($objResult["ATT_DRCW"])) {?>
                        <a href="<?echo '/RETRACK/imgpdf/' . $objResult["ATT_DRCW"]?>" download = "<? echo $objResult["ATT_DRCW"]; ?>">Download Report</a>
                    <?}else{?>
                        <label style="font-weight:normal;">No File</label>
                    <?}?>
                </td>
                <td>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <?if (isset($objResult["ATT_DFSC"])) {?>
                        <a href="<?echo  '/RETRACK/imgpdf/' . $objResult["ATT_DFSC"]?>" download = "<? echo $objResult["ATT_DFSC"]; ?>">Download POD</a>
                    <?}else{?>
                        <label style="font-weight:normal;">No File</label>
                    <?}?>
                </td>
                <td>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <?if (isset($objResult["ATT_DRTW"])) {?>
                        <a href="<?echo '/RETRACK/imgpdf/' . $objResult["ATT_DRTW"]?>" download = "<? echo $objResult["ATT_DRTW"]; ?>">Download Report</a>
                    <?}else{?>
                        <label style="font-weight:normal;">No File</label>
                    <?}?>
                </td>
                <td>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <?if (isset($objResult["ATT_DDS"])) {?>
                        <a href="<?echo '/RETRACK/imgpdf/' . $objResult["ATT_DDS"]?>" download = "<? echo $objResult["ATT_DDS"]; ?>">Download POD</a>
                    <?}else{?>
                        <label style="font-weight:normal;">No File</label>
                    <?}?>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <label>Date Requested</label>
                </td>
                <td>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <label>Received in Whse</label>
                </td>
                <td>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <label>Fwd to Service Center</label>
                </td>
                <td>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <label>Returned in Whse</label>
                </td>
                <td>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <label>Delivered in Store</label>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

```
        <table>
            <div class="toolbarModal">
                <div class="toolbar-background ">
                </div>
                <div class="toolbar-infoContainer">
                    <label style="text-indent: 10px; font-size:15px ;">Mobile No.:</label> <label style="color:blue;"><?=$objResult["MOBILE"];?></label><br/><br/>

                    <label style = "position: absolute; left:25px;">ASN Type Description</label>
                    <label style = "position: absolute; left:325px;">IMEI No.</label> 
                    <label style = "position: absolute; left:565px;">MTPOS Invoice</label>
                    <label style = "position: absolute; left:805px;">Mybss Case</label>
                    </br>
                    <label style="position: absolute; left:45px; font-size:18px;"><?=$objResult["RETURN_TYPE"];?></label>
                    <label style="position: absolute; left:305px; font-size:18px;"><?=$objResult["IMEI"];?></label>
                    <label style="position: absolute; left:555px; font-size:18px;"><?=$objResult["INVOICE"];?></label>
                    <label style="position: absolute; left:800px; font-size:18px;"><?=$objResult["MYBSS"];?></label><br/><br/>

                    <label style = "position: absolute; left:25px;";>Client/Store Name:</label> 
                    <label style = "position: absolute; left:565px;">Item Description:</label>
                    <br />
                    <label style="position: absolute; left:25px; font-size:18px;"><?=$objResult["CLIENT_STORE"];?></label> 
                    <label style="position: absolute; left:555px; font-size:18px;"><?=$objResult["DESCR"];?></label> <br /><br/>

                    <label style = "text-indent: 10px">Diagnosis:</label>                   
                    <?if (isset($objResult["ATT_DIAGNOSIS"])) {?>
                        <a href="<?echo "/RETRACK/imgpdf/" . $objResult["ATT_DIAGNOSIS"] ?>" download = "<? echo $objResult["ATT_DIAGNOSIS"]; ?>">Download Report</a>

                    <?}else{?>
                        <label style="font-weight:normal;">No File</label>
                    <?}?>
                    <br/>
                    <textarea name="Text1" cols="110" rows="5"  style="text-indent: 20px; font-size:15px ;" readonly="readonly"><?print $objResult["DIAGNOSIS"];?></textarea><br/>
                </div>
            </div>
        </table>


            <!--div id= "displayWindow4"></div-->

          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default"> <a href = "RLLAMES-PC" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#contactus" data-remote="false">Contact Us</a></button>&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>  

<div id="contactus" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header" style="background-color: #333666;">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Contact Us</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">

        <table>
            <a href="" title=""><img src="images/drq.png" alt="Smiley face" width="65" height="45"  align="left"></a>
            <tr>
              <td><label for="label">Hotline:</label></td>
              <td><label for="label">982-9999</label></td>
            </tr> 
            <tr>
              <td><label for="label">Email:</label></td>
              <td><label for="label"><a href="mailto:support.phi-nsc@dbschenker.com?Subject=Globe%20Retrack" target="_top">support.phi-nsc@dbschenker.com</a></label></td>
            </tr> 
        </table> 
            <div id= "displayWindow9"></div>

          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
<?  
        }
    //}
//}
?>
```

error message : Notice: Undefined index: data1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\Globe\retrackView.php on line 277

Comment: i see code, i see no explanation of the problem

Comment: what with the + in the query and the sql injection ?

Comment: the problem is .$_POST['data1']. has no value [undefined index : data1]

Comment: You say _I have a PHP script inside the modal_ do you mean you are trying to run PHP inside a javascript Modal Dialog?

Comment: yes it is valid sql query using msSql

Comment: yes running php inside modal dialog

Comment: You mean the AJAX call is in the modal dialog?

Comment: Thats really does not help us much even when I paste it into the question where it should have gone in the forst place

Comment: no I used this
`code: $result2=sqlsrv_query( $conn,$strSQL1, $params2,array(
"Scrollable" => 'keyset'));
while($objResult = sqlsrv_fetch_array(
$result2,SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC )).....`


then I used it like :

<label><?if (isset($objResult["DATE_RECEIVED_WHSE"])){ 
print date('m-d-Y h:i A',strtotime($objResult["DATE_RECEIVED_WHSE"]));}?>
</label>

Comment: Small point: You cannot debug this and you can see all of it. Imagine how difficult it is for us to help when you are only showing us fragments of what is actually going on

Comment: sorry sir I've already updated .. thanks

Comment: got it working without redirect by adding new php file having the query to database then pass the data to retrackView.php using json_encode and call it via jquery on reTrackView.php ..